# Как симулировать значение размера экрана "браузера" на python?

Tags: python

Всем привет. Как с использованием python можно подменить значение размера экрана для сервера? Хочу эмулировать запрос от реального браузера.

Comment: зачем это нужно?

Comment: для парсинга сайтов...

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да

Comment: Попорбуй Selenium?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я его активно использую в скрэпинге, но сейчас мне нужно сделать больше 100 миллионов запросов к серверу амазона. На селениуме можн ждать вечно, пока эти запросы будут отправляться :)

Comment: в запросе к серверу размер экрана никак не указывается. но js на стороне клиента может узнать размер экрана и использовать это в запросе. планируете ли вы выполнять js в вашем эмуляторе?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, ничего не планировал, но если есть информация, давайте. Просто сейчас особо нету времени экспериментировать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: уточните свой вопрос, что именно вы планируете делать? какие это будет сайты? зачем надо эмулировать размер экрана, если у вас не будет выполняться js?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, в комментарии выше я указал, что хочу парсить британский амазон. Нужно сделать больше 100.000.000 запросов. Хочется знать, как можно обойти блокировку по ip, не используя прокси. Я думаю размер экрана имеет значение на распознавание робота. Надо как то передать размер экрана серверу.

Comment: Вы уверены что amazon выдержит 100.000.000 запросов? Это же практически DDOS атака...

Comment: @AndrioSkur, у меня получилось :) всего два заголовка добавил :)

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да нет. Я просто нашел решение для обхода блокировки скрипта для сайта амазона. Оказалось дело не в вопросе, но мне очень интересно, как можно решить его.

Comment: @RezvanovMaxim никак, размер экрана не передается при стандартном http запросе.